# OpenGL - Mapping between x and y in glVertex2f(x, y) to screen integer coordinates

Tags: c, opengl

I would like to know how the vertices of `glVertex2f(x, y)` map to actual screen integer co-ordinates.

I intend to use a complex plane with minR, minI and maxR, maxI (I and R - Imaginary and Real part), such that the plane gets mapped to 512 x 512 pixels on the screen. I have points of 512 steps between the min and max values.

The mapping between the vertices is unclear since, I had to scale the my planar image using `glScalef(100, 100, 0)` to get it roughly fit the screen. But still, a large portion of it is left blank.

Please note that I am using the `glBegin(GL_POINTS)` routine to map the points in the plane to the screen. 
The code looks thus,

```
for (X = 0; X < 512; X++)
    for (Y = 0; Y < 512; Y++)
    glVertex2f (Complexplane[X][Y].real, Complexplane[X][Y].imag);
```

P.S.:

```
Complexplane[0][0].real = -2, Complexplane[0][0].imag = -1.2
Complexplane[511][511].real = 1.0, Complexplane[0][0].imag = 1.8
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you haven't set the projection or modelview matrices - they will be set to the identity matrix by default BTW...

For X,Y coordinates, a point will be visible if: `-1 <= X <= 1, -1 <= Y <= 1`

The [glViewport](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glViewport.xml) function describes how this range is mapped to the window. It is initially set to (0, 0, window_width, window_height) when the GL context is created. The fact that `glScale(100, 100, 0)` is only taking up a portion of the window suggests that you are applying another transform elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

The mapping depends on the transformation matrices set. In up to OpenGL-2 the pipeline is

```
v_eye = ModelviewMatrix * v
v_projected = ProjectionMatrix * v_eye
v_clipped = clip(v_projected)
v_NDC.xyzw = v_clipped.xyzw / v_clipped.w
```

The default matrices are identity, so the only operation applied in the default state is the clipping. `v_NDC` then undergoes the viewport transform:

```
p.xyz = (v_NDC.xyz + 1) * viewport.wh / 2 + viewport.xy
```